# Round ties to even with floating point subtraction

Tags: floating-point

Rounding does not work the way I would expect with floating point subtraction.

IEEE754-2008, 4.3.1 says "roundTiesToEven...if the two nearest floating-point numbers bracketing an unrepresentable infinitely precise result are equally near, the one with an even least significant digit shall be delivered"

The Intel docs say this is the default mode and define it more explicitly:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/503710

I'll first walk through floating point addition--which works as I would expect--to validate my assumptions. I will then modify my test case slightly to show where my understanding breaks down.

Let's take two single floating point numbers, represented here in the 'binary32' format:

```
S Exponent       Significand
0 10000010 00000000000000000000001  (0x41000001)
    130

0 01111111 00000000000000000000100  (0x3F800004)
    127
```

To add them, I shift the significand of the number with the smaller exponent (second operand) to the right 3 places (I've also added the implicit leading 1 here):

```
   1.00000000000000000000001
+  0.00100000000000000000000  100
 ----------------------------
   1.00100000000000000000001
```

Because the shifted out values are mid way between the two (100), it should round to the sum to the even value:

```
1.00100000000000000000010
```

In binary, the full value is:

```
0 10000010 00100000000000000000010 (0x41100002)
```

I can verify this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

union uval {
   float fval;
   int32_t ival;
};

int main()
{
    union uval a, b, c;
    a.ival = 0x41000001;
    b.ival = 0x3F800004;
    c.fval = a.fval + b.fval;
    printf("%08x\n", c.ival);
}
```

Prints:

```
./a.out
41100002
```

If I add one to the first operand:

```
    a.ival = 0x41000002;
```

I get the same thing. It has rounded *down* to the even result:

```
./a.out
41100002
```

So far, so good. However, if I use the original values and modify the second parameter to be negative by setting the sign bit to 1:

```
a.ival = 0x41000001;
b.ival = 0xBF800004;
```

I get:

```
./a.out
40E00001
```

Which is:

```
0 10000001 11000000000000000000001
    129
```

The result should still have been mid-way between the two values after the second parameter was aligned. Why didn't it round to an even value in this case?

Comment: Why do you expect the final result to be half way between rather than exactly representable?

Comment: Because I shifted the digits '100' out of the second operand when aligning it (the exponents of the source operands differ by 3).

Comment: Have you thought about what is happening at the high significance end, and the change in result exponent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand the final result, it is important to remember that rounding is the very last step in IEEE 754 arithmetic. It is done as though exact through normalization, and then rounded.

Looking at the high significance end of the two calculations, both operands have zeros in the explicit bits. The implicit one bit in `b` is right shifted three places to match the exponents:

```
1.000
0.001
```

Adding these gives 1.001, so the exponent remains the same as `a`, and there is an explicit one bit in the result.

Subtracting them gives 0.111. Normalization shifts this left one bit, to get rid of the leading 0, giving 1.110. Two explicit one bits are stored in the result.

Now look at the low significance end. The raw subtract would leave a one bit in the "half way between" position. The left shift due to normalization turns that into the least significant stored bit, and the result is exact.